# How to display Korean letters from SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

We have setup all required settings(NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS)in database. But still not visible Korean text from SQL developer. Could you suggest me what setting need to be required from SQL developer for visible the Korean text.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067064/how-to-make-sql-developer-display-non-english-character-correctly-instread-of-di may help.

Comment: @K.Madden, Thanks, But in my sql developer doesn't have 'Arial Unicode MS'(Predefined Font), how can i get this Font from SQL developer , could you suggest me . i tried my best but still i couldn't get see the Korean text

Comment: is `Microsoft YaHei` avaiable in your preference -> font name

Comment: @K.Madden, As you suggested i changed but no luck, still i couldn't see the Korean text. Thanks for the your effort..

Comment: @srinunivas show us..take a screenshot and add to your question showing your data and font setting

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Thanks much for your suggestion. Now am able to see the Korean text with the Font is "Malgun Gothic Semilight" . As you suggested i checked the font , now i changed my font is "Malgun Gothic Semilight", so i can able to see the Korean text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should 'just work' assuming your data in the database isn't corrupted and you have a font in SQL Developer configured that supports your characters

In the preferences, take your data that isn't 'working' paste it in, and then cycle through the fonts until you find one that DOES work

[image]