# Oracle SQL Developer: Arial Unicode MS and other fonts not available

Tags: oracle, encoding, utf-8, oracle-sqldeveloper

In SQL Developer's (*version 21.2.1.204 under Windows 10*) Preferences, under Code Editor \ Fonts, several expected entries do not show up in the list of available fonts even though the limitation to monospaced fonts is lifted, and Environment \ Encoding is set to 'UTF-8'. Among these are "Arial Unicode MS" and Google's Noto fonts.

According to this post...
[how to make sql developer display non-English character correctly instread of displaying squares?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067064/how-to-make-sql-developer-display-non-english-character-correctly-instread-of-di)
... and others, at least "Arial Unicode MS" should be available.

And yes, these fonts are installed and work fine in all other applications that allow font selection.

What's going on?

Comment: It looks like you are not the only person with this problem - see [Fonts in SQL Developer](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4476035/fonts-in-sql-developer). Are you running on a Windows machine, and the missing fonts were not installed by an admin user? If so, try reinstalling one of the missing fonts as an administrator to see if that resolves the issue for that font. (If that is the case then it is a bug in SQL Developer, but at least you have a workaround.)

Comment: Not sure that's a bug, more like just how it works.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Since other products do not have that limitation, and users are confused by the missing fonts when using SQL Developer, it might be worth considering whether it is an undocumented (?) usability issue or bug, rather than simply dismissing the issue because that's _"just how it works"_. It's completely reasonable for users to expect fonts they have installed to be available. And if there is a good reason why that can't/won't be addressed, then at least formally document the limitation.

Comment: I've yet to duplicate this behavior myself, so I can't comment further. Also, the underlying IDE comes from the JDeveloper FCP, and the issue/design limitation/bug lies there, and not specifically with SQL Developer.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: not a good sign if a shrug-like comment like the one you made comes from someone with your (deservedly) outstanding reputation. If "that's [...] just how it works", then why did/does it use to work for some people, and not for others? It's bad enough that in 2022, Oracle still makes us go through several hoops to get proper handling of "foreign" characters - but if the supplied front end tool does not support the obvious choices for actually displaying the results, I find this... interesting, to say the least.

Comment: @skomisa: Thanks for the link. There is a posting there that says, "Resinstalling  [the fonts] as administrator solved the issue". Sadly, this option is not currently available to me as I have no admin rights on my developer machine.

Comment: Use the Hack font that we ship with the tool. I can file a bug for you, but if the font isn't avail to the application, we can't use it. Again, I don't have a reproducible case to track down at the moment, just this theory.

Comment: @FrankAnsbach See the answers and comments to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55112673/2985643) about missing fonts on Windows. It relates to NetBeans, but the workarounds discussed might still be worth trying if you can’t reinstall fonts as an admin.

Comment: and yes, SQLDev does ship with netbeans resources, so this could be DIRECTLY related

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Since NetBeans also faces this issue, perhaps the  problem arises from Windows having changed the rules for font access, and the only tools **unaffected** by that (hypothetical) change are the special cases of browsers, and tools written by Microsoft? If so, there may be nothing that Oracle can do to address it, unless there is an alternative API to build the font list that specifically includes user installed fonts.

Comment: **I have been able to verify on another workstation that fonts installed with local admin privileges ("for all users") DO show up in SQL Developer.**

I guess this means the original question can be considered as "answered", though a real solution is pending.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: thanks for chiming in again. I would gladly accept your offer "I can file a bug for you" as this seems to be the proper way to investigate _where_ in those layers of software components SQL Developer is built upon the fonts get lost.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: 
>> Use the Hack font that we ship with the tool.
I _do_ use the Hack font, because it is an improvement over Courier New from an aesthetic point of view. Number-of-Glyphs-wise, however, it is not, hence my wish to use alternatives which cover a wider spectrum of the UTC character set.

Comment: @FrankAnsbach Even though it seems that there is no immediate fix for your problem, please consider posting (and accepting) an answer anyway, since that is much more helpful to the SO community than a few comments below the question. I’ll be happy to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to verify on another workstation that fonts installed with local admin privileges ("for all users") DO show up in SQL Developer. I guess this means the original question can be considered as "answered", though a real solution is pending.